# How do I properly join to do aggregation on the same column twice?

Tags: sql, join

Grain of the table is similar to `state_id | county_id | city_id | eventtype`. Where eventtype is binary; it is equal to 1 or 2.
I want to group by all 3 columns and see the aggregate sums of eventtypes where it equals 1 and 2. How do I properly do this?

When I do an inner join of

```
select *
from 
(state_id, county_id, city_id, sum(eventtype) as views
select 
poptable
where eventtype = 1 
group by state_id, county_id, city_id) l
INNER JOIN
(state_id, county_id, city_id, sum(eventtype) as passes
select 
poptable
where eventtype = 2
group by state_id, county_id, city_id) r
ON l.state_id = r.state_id
and l.county_id = r.county_id
and l.city_id = r.city_id
```

I get about 500 rows. But if I do a full outer join, I get about 3000 rows. I understand that there would be missing combinations, so how do I get them to appear together?

Comment: what database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select state_id, county_id, city_id,
       sum(case when eventtype = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as views_1,
       sum(case when eventtype = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as views_2
from poptable
group by state_id, county_id, city_id;
```

I'm not sure why you are doing `sum(eventtype)`.  It seems strange that you would want "1" to be summed in the first case and "2" in the second.

Answer (score 1):

```
select state_id, country_id, city_id, 
case when eventtype = 1 then sum(eventtype) end as passes,
case when eventtype = 2 then sum(eventtype) end as views
from tablename where eventtype in (1,2)
group by state_id, country_id, city_id
```

Is this what you are trying to do?